# set and get android button text programatically

Tags: android

How can i get the text set on the button inside the on-click() class?
i need to get the button text for sq l select statement

```
 tableLayout.addView(tableRow);
    int a = 0;
    for (Integer j = 0; j < count; j++)
    {
        Button b = new Button(getApplicationContext());
        b.setText(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("jour")));
         b.setId(a++);

        tableRow.addView(b);
        b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Integer fff = v.getId();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), fff.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                Log.d("TAG", "The index is");
            }
        });
        c.moveToNext() ;


enter code here
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are adding the Button to table row `tableRow.addView(b);`. I at first look at the code din't see it. Missed it.

So Make it final

```
 final Button b = new Button(getApplicationContext());
 // Use ActivtiyContext
 final Button b = new Button(ActivityName.this);
 // posted a link at the end read it.
```

An anonymous class cannot access local variables in its enclosing scope that are not declared as final or effectively final.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html#accessing

Inside onClick

```
 public void onClick(View v) {

        String value = b.getText().toString()
        }
```

Also check

[When to call activity context OR application context?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7298731/when-to-call-activity-context-or-application-context)

Answer (score 2):

You can type caste the view to button and use it to getText().

```
tableLayout.addView(tableRow);
int a = 0;
for (Integer j = 0; j < count; j++)
{
    Button b = new Button(getApplicationContext());
    b.setText(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("jour")));
     b.setId(a++);

    tableRow.addView(b);
    b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Integer fff = v.getId();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), fff.toString(),                
           Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

          Button b = (Button)v;
           String buttonText = b.getText().toString();
            Log.d("TAG", "The text is " + buttonText);
        }
    });
    c.moveToNext() ;
```

Answer (score 1):

As per my way create `String Array` and :

```
String Title = new String[count];
```

And now implement like this:

```
 for (int j = 0; j < count; j++)
{
    Button b = new Button(getApplicationContext());
    b.setText(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("jour")));
    b.setId(j);

    Title[a] = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("jour");

    b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v1) {

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Button click on(): "+Title[v1.getId()].toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            Log.d("TAG", "The index is: "+v1.getId());
        }
    });
    tableRow.addView(b);
    c.moveToNext() ;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

- First you give onclick event for Button like (buttonClick).

  ```
  final Button testButton = new Button(getApplicationContext());

  void buttonClick(View v){
   Log.v("text", testButton.getText().toString()); // get the text
   testButton.setText("sometext");  //to change the text
  }
  ```

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html#accessing

Comment: `Final` is not `final`

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
    public void onClick(View v) {

    String value = (Button)v.getText().toString()
    }
```